# How to store and retrieve error arrays in $_SESSION

Tags: php, html, arrays, http-redirect

I'm having trouble with storing and retrieving error messages after a redirect. I'm only getting 'Array' or 'Array ( [0] => No files were added. )' as a result.
Below I describe what exactly I'm doing:

I'm working on a php script which uploads files with the help of a submit form. However, since a number of errors can occur during the upload process, I've stored the errors in an array named $errors. An example of how I added the error messages to the array:

`$errors[] = "The error message is placed here";`

After the upload process succeeds (or fails, in the case of errors), the page is reloaded to clear the form, among other things. This is (I think) also needed to display an error with php when a user submits a blank form (but maybe there's another way to do this, but I don't know). To inform the user about errors that may have popped up during the upload process, I want to store this $errors array in a session variable, #_SESSION['errors']. I'm hoping this helps bringing the errors over to the refreshed page.

Anyway, this is the (rough) script that I've got, which shows where the redirect is situated.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    [upload script]
}else{
    $errors[] = "No files were added.";
    $_SESSION[ 'errors' ] = $errors;
    header( 'Location:' . $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] );
    exit();
}
```

Of course I put session_start(); underneath my php opening tag (only error_reporting(E_ALL) and ini_set('display_errors', '1') are above the session_start(), nothing else).

I tested if the array was sent, by including the following code directly underneath the session_start():

```
if(isset($_SESSION[ 'errors' ])){
    $errors[] = $_SESSION[ 'errors' ];
    unset( $_SESSION[ 'errors' ] );
    print_r($errors);
}
```

I discovered that the unset was needed, otherwise the same errors would be saved in the $_sessions['errors'] over and over again after refreshing. The print_r($errors) gave the following output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => No files were added. ) )
```

So I guess the $errors array survived the redirect, right?

So, on to the displaying of the actual errors. I placed the $errors = $_SESSION['errors'] code in the place where I want to show my errors (in my body tag, underneath the menu). Here's the code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION[ 'errors' ])){
    $errors[] = $_SESSION[ 'errors' ];
    unset( $_SESSION[ 'errors' ] );

}
if(isset($errors)){
    echo "<div id=\"errorLog\" class=\"errorLogCl\" onClick=\"this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';\">";
    foreach ( $errors as $e ) {
        echo $e;
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

However, this only gives 'Array' as value. I've tried other options, such as print_r or:

```
foreach ($errors as $key => $errorvalue){
    echo($errorvalue);
}
```

But I still get only 'Array' or 'Array ( [0] => No files were added. )' as a result.

What am I doing wrong and how do I properly store and retrieve the error messages I'm saving in the $errors and $_SESSIONS['errors'] array? Or is there a better way of sending (multiple) error messages over a redirect?

Comment: "_the page is reloaded to clear the form, among other things_" My suggestion is to avoid storing error states in session and improve the reason you lose the error data, the page refresh. The form could be cleared without needing this behavior if you don't re-print the default values under the error condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As print_r shows you $error is an array of arrays, that conatain the messages. You either have to change (don't push the error into another array):

```
$_SESSION[ 'errors' ][] = $errors;
```

to:

```
$_SESSION[ 'errors' ] = $errors;
```

Or fix your for loop from (iterate over the internal array(s)):

```
foreach ($errors as $key => $errorvalue){
  echo($errorvalue);
}
```

to:

```
foreach ($errors as $key => $errorvalue){
  if(is_array($errorvalue)) {
    foreach ($errorvalue as $em) {
      echo $em;
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Actually I'm slighty confused now. These three lines would mean that you need **3** foreach loops:

```
$errors[] = "No files were added.";
$_SESSION[ 'errors' ][] = $errors;
$errors[] = $_SESSION[ 'errors' ];
```

But the print_r statement points to **2** foreach:

```
print_r($errors)
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => No files were added. ) )
```

The first part fits nicely with your fix. You removed one bracket pair [], and used two foreach, and I think your code will work if you remove [] from the third line I copied. But I can't explain the print_r output. Are you sure if wasn't from print_r($e)?

Comment: Not exactly your answer, but I've got it working now. I've got the $_SESSION[ 'errors' ] = $errors in combination with the foreach > if > foreach loop. Can you maybe explain why this is?

Comment: I've had to change the if(isset($errors)) to if(isset($errors[0])) as well, otherwise the div errorlog would show all the time.

Comment: When reading back the session, you use `$errors[] = $_SESSION[ 'errors' ];`. This adds the session array to the errors array and creates $errors if it doesn't exist. It also explains why you need foreach > if > foreach and $errors[0]. But I don't remember seeing it before. Give me a few minutes to look through your edits, and try to explain it better.

Comment: Maybe this helps, I've added the current (working) script to a jsfiddle. Not the best way of showing you my code, but it's something, haha. Just check the HTML part of the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/75ndg4h8/

Comment: I edited a few more thoughts into the question. For PHP code sharing I prefer 3v4l. Like https://3v4l.org/kQAhr or https://3v4l.org/bNu3Y

Comment: Thanks! Will give you a link in a moment. I've put 'print_r($errors)' underneath 'unset($_SESSION['errors']') and it gave me this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => No files were added. ) ). This is with the working code.

Comment: For convenience sake, I've included the config.php code. It has some lines of the error array in it too. https://3v4l.org/q1DAr Ignore the upload code, still working on that so it's quite messy ;)

Comment: Okay, cleaned it up a bit from your recommendations, now it's this (no changes to code which goes above it). https://3v4l.org/nJaOf Works as a charm :)

Comment: Great. I think we can ignore the problem about 2 or 3 loops. 1 in much cleaner. Have fun developing your application.

Comment: Thanks! Your help and explanations are much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of foreach:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['errors'] as $result)  
    echo($result)
```

should work. The reason is that $_SESSION is an array of arrays.

Think of it like this:
You tell PHP to make an list of items called $errors. You then tell PHP to put this list into a list of lists. The reason it didn't work is that you are trying to show the list itself, and not the items one-by-one.

Comment: actually, you need a double foreach